# regular expression to extract this string

Tags: regex

I have the following string

- jenkins-client-1.4
- perl-5.16
- ruby-1.9
- 10gen-mms-agent-1.0

  Is it possible to use regular expression to extract terms with the dash and version stripped out to end up with something like the following?
- jenkins-cleint
- perl
- ruby
- 10gen-mms-agent

Thx,
-peter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will do it: `(.*?)-[0-9][0-9.]+`

`.*?` matches anything, but as little as possible. This is the capture group you want to extract.
`-[0-9][0-9.]` matches a hyphen, then a digit, then any number of digits and periods.

Answer (score 2):

Example for C#

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string[] terms = new string[] {
                "jenkins-client-1.4",
                "perl-5.16",
                "ruby-1.9",
                "10gen-mms-agent-1.0"
            };
        Regex termRegex = new Regex(@"^(.+)-(\d+[.]\d+)$");
        foreach (string term in terms)
            if (termRegex.IsMatch(term))
                Console.WriteLine(termRegex.Match(term).Groups[1].Value);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```